# How to include sub-dependencies of a custom library added into SpringBoot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot

There is a custom library which has some Maven dependencies. When this library is added into SpringBoot project, these dependencies are not included in the Maven-Dependencies section of a SpringBoot project. 
I.e. SpringBoot project compiles, but then has runtime exceptions.
What should be done with the custom library, or how to build its Manifest.mf, to have this sub-dependencies picked up by SpringBoot?

Comment: You should probably add more detail to your question (e.g. the maven POM, project structure, etc.), but it sounds like you'll have to add the missing dependencies to your own pom.xml so they are loaded into your project.

Comment: For example, if I add <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId> into my SB project - all drools sup-dependencies are included in Maven-Dependencies section of SB project, which are later resolved by Maven and included in SB BOOT-INF/lib folder. But if I add  <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId> into my custom library and then include custom lib to my SB project, then drools lib is not added as a transitive dependency, but I wish it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case adding <scope>compile</scope> to the library's pom dependencies solved the issue. Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 0):

What i get from your issue description is that you are having a pom.xml for current application and one of the dependency mentioned there is having issues while packaging i.e. its has further dependencies that needs to be packages.

In that case you can do 2 things:

- Repackage your custom library to include all its dependencies and forming one fat jar which you can then refer as your dependency.
- Else you can take the pom of your custom library and add all the dependencies as your project dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking that instead of copy-pasting pom, I could configure the lib to have its dependencies in Manifest.mf file somehow and it could be used in the main project to get them resolved.

Comment: Actually ideally transitive dependencies get resolved if the custom library is also added as maven artifacts(i.e. can be from your local maven repo only). I feel you are adding your custom library as system scope level causing its not to leverage custom libs pom.xml hence preventing transitive dependencies discovery.